# R - no values after plotting by using ggplot2 package

Tags: r, ggplot2

For today, I've been focusing on plotting my data. 4 have succeeded but the following one is quite troublesome. Let's say that my data frame is called `test`. Some test data:

```
          Date Persnr  Holiday     AmountHolidays
1   2011-01-01  55312  FALSE       3
2   2011-01-01  55316  FALSE       4
3   2011-01-01  55325  FALSE       1.5
4   2011-01-01  76065  "Christmas" 2
5   2011-01-01  71928  "Christmas" 0
6   2011-01-01  72558  FALSE       3
....
10  2013-01-02  55312  FALSE       10
11  2013-01-02  55316  "Summer"    3.5
12  2013-01-02  55325  "Summer"    0
13  2013-01-02  76065  FALSE       0
```

I've used this code:

```
ggplot(data=test, aes(x=Persnr, y=AmountHolidays, fill=Holiday)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

What I want to see is a graph of the total amount of holidays of each Persnr visualised in a stacked bar chart sorted by the holiday (e.g. christmas, summer, etc).

This is what I got by using the code:
[image: test]

I got no values whatsoever. I'd like to have an overview of the total amount of holidays of each person sorted by holiday.

Some info of my data frame.

```
str(df.data)

'data.frame':   490 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Date          : chr  "2011-01-01" "2011-01-01" "2011-01-01" "2011-01-01" ...
 $ Persnr        : num  55312 55316 55325 76065 71928 ...
 $ AmountHolidays: num  0 3 0 0 1 0.5 0 0.5 2 0 ...
 $ Holiday       : chr  "FALSE" "FALSE" "FALSE" "FALSE" ...
```

All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `Persnr` is treated like a numeric value, so x-axis is continuous with a lot of empty spaces, so the width of each existing bar is lass than 1 pixel. What you probably want is

```
ggplot(data=dd, aes(x=factor(Persnr), y=AmountHolidays, fill=Holiday)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]